# Using a picture as background in the filebrowser Nemo for directories which are not the home directory

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, file-browser

im currently configuring Linux Mint Cinnamon 17 on a SSD as a Christmas present.
I want to have the file-browser nemo display a .jpeg instead of a plain background in
directories which should not be carelessly messed with.  I just thought this would be a fun way to warn someone who's only used windows until now.
Is there any way to add such a custom background?

Until now I've only found out how to change the background color or font.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Work in `nemo` 4.8.6, putting the `.png` (not `.jpg`) in the same folder as `gtk.css`:

```css
background-image: 
    url("Icetwigs.png");
  color: #e5e5e5;
    
}


.nemo-window .sidebar .view {
  background-image: 
    url("bklat.png");
  color: #e5e5e5;
}
```